# com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'play.application'

Tags: playframework, guice, sbt-assembly

I am using sbt assembly plugin to build a binary distribution of my play application. but every time I want to start the appp I get the following error

```
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'play.application'
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:152)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:145)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:172)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:176)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:193)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:198)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getIsNull(SimpleConfig.java:208)
    at play.api.ConfigLoader$$anon$4.load(Configuration.scala:1078)
    at play.api.ConfigLoader$$anon$4.load(Configuration.scala:1076)
    at play.api.PlayConfig.get(Configuration.scala:918)
    at play.utils.Reflect$.configuredClass(Reflect.scala:112)
    at play.api.ApplicationLoader$.apply(ApplicationLoader.scala:56)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:46)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:22)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
```

It seems the key play.application has not been configured in application.conf file. But I haven't found any in play framework documentation, explaining how to configure this key. I appreiciate any advice

Answer (score 3):

After struggling with sbt assembly plugins and merge strategies, I gave up and made the decision to use `sbt dist` which generates a universal installer. BTW the .bat generated sucks and does not work, so use the sh script to start the application.